# Failure in make_pair from custom class

Tags: c++, class, memory-management

`std::make_pair` fails with my custom `Matrix` class:

```
template <Scalar T>
std::pair<Matrix<T>, Matrix<T>> LUDecomposition(Matrix<T>& A) {
    assert(A.R == A.C);
    std::size_t n = A.R;
    Matrix<T> L (n, n);
    Matrix<T> U (n, n);
    // computation details ...
    return std::make_pair(L, U);
}
```

My `Matrix` class definition:

```
template <Scalar T>
class Matrix {
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;
public:
    const std::size_t R;
    const std::size_t C;

    // implementation details, not related to this question
};
```

The compiler complains:

```
      template<typename _U1, typename _U2, typename
           enable_if<_PCCP::template
               _MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>()
              && !_PCCP::template
               _ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>(),
                         bool>::type=false>
    explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
    : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_pair.h:361:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_pair.h:360:38: error: no type named ��type�� in ��struct std::enable_if<false, bool>��
  360 |                          bool>::type=false>
```

I don't see why. Isn't my `Matrix` class implicitly move convertible by default?

If I fix `std::make_pair(L, U)` to `std::make_pair(std::move(L), std::move(U))`, then the code compiles but a segfault occurs.

Should I really define my custom move constructor and move assignment operators?

Comment: Self-answer: ```std::make_pair(std::move(L), std::move(U))``` was the remedy enough. The segfault was from a different source. Too bad that I can't use C++17-style ```return {std::move(L), std::move(U)};```. Why RVO is not enabled in this case? :(

Comment: Seems that the issue is really the `std::unique_ptr`, which is not copyable, only movable.

Comment: @frozenca RVO is likely applied, but RVO is related to the return value, which is of `std::pair` type.